# Tag extra information to differentiate numbers in a list

Tags: python, list

In Python, I have a list of results that occurred in a chronological order:

`results = [2,6,4,5,2,3,1,8,4,4]`

But the results came from two different machines. I want to treat the data that came from each machine slightly differently.

So perhaps:

results = [**2**,6,4,5,2,**3**,1,8,**4**,4]

where the bold numbers are from machine A and the non-bold numbers are from machine B. I think that I need to some how 'tag' the numbers in some way so that the code can recognize which machine they were from. I realize that I could create two separate lists, but then I would lose the chronology. I need to keep them in the order that they occurred.

So I need to tag the extra information to the results. Is there a standard way to do this?

Comment: There is no *standard* way to do this, you could create a list of tuples with the second member being the machine ID but it depends what you really want to do with this data, the size, whether you expect to mutate it often etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are different solution for your problem.

#### First example

You can have one list of tuples. The first element is your data and the second is the machine that comes the data: `(data, machine)`

```python
results = [(2,1),(6,2),(4,2),(5,2),(2,2),(3,1),...]
```

For going over the data you just need a for of two elements

```python
for data, machine in results:
  print("The data is %d from machine %d." % (data, machine))
```

#### Second example

Although you can have two list, one with the data and another with the id of the machine

```python
results = [2,6,4,5,2,3,1,8,4,4]
machine = [1,2,2,2,2,1,2,2,1,2]
```

The code for go over you data is as simple like this :

```python
for i, idmach in enumarate(machine):
  print("The data is %d from machine %d." % (results[i], idmach))
```

(*those could be in a more pythonic way but it is an example*)

Answer (score 2):

How about just creating a second list holding the positions of each 'tagged' element of the first list thus retaining order in the first one?

`tagged=[0,5,8]`

And access the tagged elements easily:
`tags = [results[i] for i in tagged]`

Answer (score 1):

keep list of tuples instead were left element is a number, and right is a machine number from

```
results = [(2,0),(6,1),(4,1),(5,1),(2,1),(3,0),(1,1),(8,1),(4,0),(4,1)]

machine0 = [ x for x,y in results if y == 0]
machine1 = [ x for x,y in results if y == 1]
```

print(machine0)

[2, 3, 4]

print(machine1)

[6, 4, 5, 2, 1, 8, 4]

Answer (score 1):

As has been mentioned, you could store your data as a `tuple`. If you are getting data from two different machines, then you could build your result list as follows:

```
import itertools

def machine_a():
    for data_a in [1,5,10,20]:
        yield data_a

def machine_b():
    for data_b in [20,30,50,100,110,120]:
        yield data_b

results = []

for data_a, data_b in itertools.izip_longest(machine_a(), machine_b()):
    if data_a:
        results.append(('a', data_a))

    if data_b:
        results.append(('b', data_b))

for machine, data in results:
    print machine, data
```

This would then display the following results:

```
a 1
b 20
a 5
b 30
a 10
b 50
a 20
b 100
b 110
b 120
```

Obviously in your case, the data would not be simply interleaved, but this shows you how to go about building the list in a simple case.